# Ember.js REST Auth Headers

Tags: authentication, ember.js, token

I've been struggling with this for too long now. I have an Expressjs server that provides an endpoint to login. The response I get has a JWT token, expiring in an hour. All good.

On the Emberjs side, I can successfully authenticate and get the token (using ember-simple-auth and ember-simple-auth-token). This works well for protecting my routes. But I can't for the life of me update the RESTAdapter headers to include my new authorization token.

I've tried:

- using $.ajaxPrefilter to set the Authorization header. Didn't work
- accessing "this.get('session.secure.token')" from the RESTAdapter. Thats undefined.

Please, if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be eternally grateful. All I need to do is attach the value in "session.secure.token" to the header for all RESTAdapter requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set the simple-auth config property `authorizer` to `simple-auth-authorizer:token` - in the simple-auth code it looks for this config property, looks up `simple-auth-authorizer:token` and uses this in combination with `ajaxPrefilter`.

```
// config/environment.js
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token'
};
```

Comment: I have used this. Simple-Auth is working as expected, except for the headers. I've even set the

`ENV['simple-auth-token'] = {`
`authorizationHeaderName: 'Authorization',`

But still, the RESTAdapter (or any jQuery ajax requests) do not have hat header...

Comment: I added my api server to the crossOriginWhitelist as it wasn't set, but when doing a REST request, instead of an unauthorized response (as above), it seems to invalidate the session.

Comment: Ember Simple Auth automatically handles 401 responses and invalidates the session if one occurs (at least if you're using the `ApplicationRouteMixin`). You can change that behavior by overriding the`authorizationFailed`` method in your application route.

Comment: Ah explains why its redirecting. Except it shouldn't be invalidating, cause I've just logged in. So for some reason the auth headers aren't being sent through. I'm going to start a new project and see if something fresh works.